# Python: What is the easiest way to convert from time.time() value to time.strftime() value?

Tags: python

I need to represent the time in `("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` format from the float value I am getting in the form of `time.time()`.

I already have a value that is in the form of time.time(). For example I already have a value I am getting every .3 seconds from a device which is say, 1332449493.0, ...., I would then like to convert 1332449493.0 to a strftime format.

EX:
time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", 1332449493.0) will throw a TypeError because strf requires a 9-item tuple and not a float.

Comment: By... using the `strftime` function.  Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes but time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(1332449493.0)) was what I was looking for since time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", 1332449493.0) is not the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(1332449493.0))
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get a `datetime` from it:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
```

Then you can format it however you like.

Comment: I guess i did not make my question very clear. So I already have a value that is in the form of time.time(). For example I already have a value I am getting every .3 seconds from a device which is say, 1332449493.0, ...., I would then like to convert 1332449493.0 to a strftime format. How would you do it? I am not asking how to get a timestamp

Comment: @Pythomania: the name *`fromtimestamp`* is a misnomer, it can handle a `time`